# How to pass observable fields through include tag?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a layout for the toolbar spinner:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="selectedItem"
            type="int" />
    </data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.Popup"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.Spinner"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.Spinner.Popup"
            app:selectedItem="@{selectedItem}"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</layout>
```

I include that layout in fragment layouts like below:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.contedevel.timetable.models.WeekViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.contedevel.timetable.activities.MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_spinner"
                app:selectedItem="@{model.selectedWeekPosition}"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is my `ViewModel`:

```
class WeekViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val selectedWeekPosition = ObservableInt(0)
}
```

But `selectedItem` changes once on the start of activity only. When I try to change it in `onOptionsItemSelected` a nothing happens:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    if (R.id.action_now == item?.itemId) {
        week = WeekUtils.getCurrentWeek(timetable.entity)
        viewModel.selectedWeekPosition.set(week - 1)

        return true
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

I suppose the value doesn't change due to the first layout (layout data binder) unwraps it to `Int` and the second layout binder gets `Int` instead of `ObservableInt`. But I still don't know how to fix it not to pass `ObservableInt` in the toolbar spinner binder directly.

**Does anyone know how to fix it?** Spinner binding adapter are below:

```
object SpinnerBindings {

    @BindingAdapter("selectedItem")
    @JvmStatic fun Spinner.setSelectedItem(position: Int) {
        setSelection(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your viewmodel to toolbar spinner layout.

Step 1: Add bind attribute to layout tag that contains include(fragment layouts) :

```
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Step 2: Change your data item in toolbar spinner layout:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="vmodel"
        type="com.contedevel.timetable.models.WeekViewModel" />
</data>
```

Step 3: Change your include tag like below:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_spinner"
             bind:vmodel="@{model}"/>
```

Step 4 : You have access to your viewModel in toolbar spinner layout, So:

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.Spinner"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Paper.Toolbar.Spinner.Popup"
        app:selectedItem="@{vmodel.selectedWeekPosition}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, to achieve it I need to use a wrapping class on fields. Thank you for answer!